# Laravel product filter with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have model `Product`, and I have scope Filter:

```
public function scopeFilter($query)
{
    if (request('min') && request('max')) {
        $query->where('price', '<=', request('max'))->where('price', '>=', request('min'));
    }

    if (request('attr')) {
        $query->whereHas('attribute', function ($q) {
            $q->whereIn('attribute_value_id', explode(',', request('attr')));
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

And I have frontend checkboxes with name attributes:

```
@foreach($category->attribute as $attribute)

    <section class="widget">
        <h3 class="widget-title">
            {{ $attribute->getTranslatedAttribute('title') }}
            <span class="float-right ico-down" onclick="$('#filter-{{ $attribute->id }}').slideToggle();">
                <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
            </span>
        </h3>
        <div id="#filter-{{ $attribute->id }}">
            <form id="from-{{ $attribute->id }}" action="" method="GET">
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach($attribute->attributeValue as $value)
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" 
                                        type="checkbox" 
                                        id="filter-{{ $value->id }}" 
                                        name="attr" 
                                        value="{{ $value->id }}" 
                                        onclick="this.checked ? checkFunc() : removeFunc()" 
                                        @if(request('attr') && in_array($value->id, explode(',', request('attr')))) checked @endif>

                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="filter-{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->getTranslatedAttribute('value') }}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
@endforeach

@section('js')
    <script>
        var url = '?attr=';
        function checkFunc() {
            var id = $("[name=attr]:checked").map(function () {
                      return this.value;
                }).get().join(",");


            @if(request('attr'))
                window.location.href = url + "{{ request('attr') }}," + id;
            @else
                window.location.href = url + id; 
            @endif
        };
    </script>
 @endsection
```

Filters working, but my Javascript code working badly. When I click on checkbox, and later want uncheck him, it doesn't work. And multiple click checkbox also not working, In get param I get duplicate attributes. How I can fix this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use php code outside the JS function. And below is the code, you can try this.

```
<script>
    <?php
        $attr = "";
        if(request('attr')) {
            $attr = request('attr');
        }
    ?>
    var url = '?attr='+<?php echo $attr; ?>;
    function checkFunc() {
        var id = $("[name=attr]:checked").map(function () {
                  return this.value;
            }).get().join(",");


        window.location.href = url + id; 
    };
</script>
```

Try above code.

Comment: when I uncheck checkbox, filter is not removed.